# Retrieve image from Amazon S3 private bucket using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using Angular JS and WEB API for one of my website. As per requirement of website I am using Amazon S3 to store image in the bucket.

I am using WEB API to upload image dynamically in my Amazon S3 Bucket using accesskey and secretaccess key.

But now I want to display those uploaded images(not all at once) in website using Angular JS. Please note that bucket is not public.

Can anyone please share the exact code with step by step guidelines to retrieve the image from Amazon S3 using Angular JS?

**Edited(New Addition)**

Based on the response I have added the below code:-

```
$scope.retrieveImage = function()
{
   AWS.config.update({
            accessKeyId: "MyAccessKey", secretAccessKey: "MySecretKey"
        });

   var bucket = new AWS.S3({ params: { Bucket: "MyBucket" } });

   bucket.getObject({ Key: 'Datetime.png' }, function (err, file) {
     $scope.imgUrl = "";
   });
}
```

I am getting the below error now:-

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:PortNumber' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

I have added the following CORS configuration inside permission of MyBucket:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Please let me know what to be done on this?

**Solution:-**
Amending the following CORS tag to `<AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>` works like charm. Thanks for all your responses.

Comment: Find keyword `signed URL S3`. I found good explanation here https://coderwall.com/p/mtcskq/signing-amazon-s3-urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS has a complete example on mantaing photo album in a website using S3. It includes adding, removing images and albums.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please help me in the error mentioned in my code snippet portion.